# Remove/Delete blank items in a list and print these values with a pattern in an excel file

Tags: python, string, openpyxl

basically I have these (sample) list of 'strings' NOT 'integers' of data:

```
[0]  
[1]  
[2]  
[3]  
[4]  
[5]  
[6]  47
[7]  49
[8]  51
[9]  53
[10]  55
[11]  57
[12]  59
[13]  61
[14]  63
[15]  65
```

In this case I cannot modify the data and just remove the white/blank space seen from index 0-5. I've researched quite a bit and I know that strings are immutable and I can't come up with a solution sadly. I will be transferring these output to an Excel file also. These white/blank space affects me transferring these to the excel file since it recognizes the white space as string which populates the first 6 cells with blank values.

[image: Sample result from Excel file]

Also I have difficulties in creating a pattern to populate these data in these format:

[image: Supposed to be pattern of data in Excel]

I'm using openpyxl and I've achieved populating them by column using a loop:

```
File_path = 'somepath'
Excel_file = openpyxl.load_workbook(File_path)
Sheet = excel_file.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

col = 1
for data in Sample_list:
   Sheet.cell(row = 1, column = col).value = data
   col+=1

   if col == 16:
      Excel_file.save(File_path)
      break
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your loop, you can use `isspace` to check if the element is only spaces(or even tabs and newlines) before updating it in the excel:

```
# This will fill rows 1 and 3 but you can change that as per your use case
count = 0
for data in Sample_list:
    if not data or data.isspace():
        continue
    Sheet.cell(row = 1 if count % 2 == 0 else 3, column = col).value = data
    col+=count % 2 # Column only increments when count is odd
    count+=1
```

OR you can remove all the space strings from the list beforehand:

```
Sample_list = [elem for elem in Sample_list if not elem.isspace()]
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm not quite familiar with that function I'll keep that in mind next time :) . All I have to do now is to achieve this pattern Do you have any idea how can I achieve the 'pattern' that I provided?

Comment: Happy to help! Edited to match your pattern.